# How to Make Image Width Auto Scale with Page Width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, bootstrap-4

I've seen several examples of using `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` but these are not working. I am trying to place an image within a `section` in bootstrap 4. The image is either disproportioned, too big, and does not change when the page width changes.

Note that my image is 1800px * 900px and I am trying to make the width of the banner to be the page width and the height to adjust accordingly.

HTML

```
<!-- Image Section -->
<section class="banner-cube">
  <div class="container">
    <br>  
    <div>
      <h3>Image Banner</h3>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.banner-cube {
  background: url("../imagery/cubebanner.png");
  max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: You are using a background-image and not `img` tag. max-width: 100%; and  height: auto; only work for img.
You need to set a height on `.banner-cube` - this could be a relative size to width or window and also use `background-size: cover` to allow background to fit parent

Comment: Please try using "background-size: 100%" there in you can set two value 1 for width and second one for height.

Comment: Please try this .banner-cube {
  background: url("../imagery/cubebanner.png");
  background-size: 100%; 
  height: auto;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

use this but part of image will be hide in the top and bottom.

```
.banner-cube {
  background: url("../imagery/cubebanner.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Hope that works for you.

```
.banner-cube{
  background-image: url("../imagery/cubebanner.png");
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
}
```